# WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - And 404 on browser

Tags: spring, servlets

Creating a mvc form handling and getting the  error on console

WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/controller/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

employeeForm.jsp

```html
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>  
      
    <html>  
     <head>  
        
      <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>  
     </head>  
     &body>  
    <h2>  
    Employee Data Form</h2>  
    <form:form action="/sdnext/addEmployee" method="POST">        
    <table><tbody>  
    <tr>        <td><form:label path="empId">Employee :</form:label></td>      <td><form:input path="empId"></form:input></td>    </tr>  
    <tr>      <td><form:label path="name">EmployeeName:/form:label></form:label></td>       <td><form:input path="name"></form:input></td>    </tr>  
    <tr>       <td><form:label path="age">Employee Age:</form:label></td>       <td><form:input path="age"></form:input></td>     </tr>  
    <tr>      <td><form:label path="salary">Employee Salary:</form:label></td>     <td><form:input path="salary"></form:input></td>    </tr>  
    <tr>         <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/>  </td>       </tr>  
    </tbody></table>  
    </form:form>  
    </body>  
    </html>
```

EmployeeController

```html
package com.spring.controller;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.spring.model.Employee;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
 
 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeController.class);
 
 /**
  * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
  */
   
   @RequestMapping(value = "/employeeForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
   public ModelAndView employee() {  
     return new ModelAndView("employeeForm", "command", new Employee());  
    }  
       
   @RequestMapping(value = "/addEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
   public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Employee employee, ModelMap model) {  
      model.addAttribute("name", employee.getName());  
      model.addAttribute("age", employee.getAge());  
      model.addAttribute("empId", employee.getEmpId());  
      model.addAttribute("salary", employee.getSalary());  
      return "employeeDetail";  
    }  
 }
```

Employee

```html
package com.spring.model;

public class Employee {


 private int empId;  
 private String name;  
 private Long salary;  
 private int age;
 public int getEmpId() {
  return empId;
 }
 public void setEmpId(int empId) {
  this.empId = empId;
 }
 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 public Long getSalary() {
  return salary;
 }
 public void setSalary(Long salary) {
  this.salary = salary;
 }
 public int getAge() {
  return age;
 }
 public void setAge(int age) {
  this.age = age;
 } 

}
```

web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

 <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 
 <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <!-- Processes application requests -->
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
  
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

 <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
 
 <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
 <annotation-driven />

 <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
 <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

 <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
 <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>
 
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.controller" />
 
 
 
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to to highlight two point which i found mismatch from provided inputs .

1. employeeForm.jsp url is `"/sdnext/addEmployee"`.
2. addEmployee method of EmployeeController is only mapping `"/addEmployee"`.
3. close `<form:label path="name">EmployeeName:/form:label>` correctly.

Question is about `"/sdnext"`. from given input uri path `"/sdnext"` mapping is missing.

Adding RequestMapping annotation at controller level might help.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sdnext")
class EmployeeController{
    ...
}
```

If you enable server log in DEBUG mode then spring will let you know which uri paths were mapped by web application.

Comment: `/sdnext` path is not mapped that why you are getting error what is your web application name ?. From given snippet only thing I understood that `/addEmployee` is mapped by method addEmployee.